# Не работает $stateParams в AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

В контроллере `Main`, я делаю ссылку на `$state.go('main.show', {id: id});` и в контроллере `Show` я пытаюсь получить этот параметр для дальнейшей работы с ним `console.log($stateParams.id;)`, но ничего не получается.
Консоль вообще молчит, никаких ошибок и т. д.

Что я делаю не так?

HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="Main">
    <div ng-click="open(id)">
        Text
    </div>
    <div ui-view></div>
</body>
```

controllers.js

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $stateProvider
        .state('main', {
            url: '/',
            abstract: true,
            templateUrl: 'templates/main.html',
            controller: 'Main'
        })
        .state('main.show', {
            url: 'show/:id/',
            templateUrl: 'templates/show.html',
            controller: 'Show',
        });
})

.controller('Main', function($scope, $state) {
    $scope.open = function(id) {
        $state.go('main.show', {id: id});
    }  
})

.controller('Show', function($scope, $stateParams) {
    console.log($stateParams.id);
})
```

Comment: сделай [mcve]. Чтобы можно было увидеть проблему

Comment: @Grundy, сделал

Comment: эм... а где `ui-view` куда должен вставляться шаблон для роута?

Comment: @Grundy, ой, пропустил случайно.. исправил)

Answer (score 1):

Тут плохо все: начиная с использования одного контроллера `Main` два раза

1. ng-controller="Main"
2. controller: 'Main'

В этом случае создается **два** независимых экземпляра контроллера, никак между собой не связанных.

Заканчивая вызовом функции

```
<div ng-click="open(id)">
```

При этом нигде не устанавливая значения для переменной `id`.

Если добавить недостающие `ui-view`, и указать конкретное значение передаваемое в функцию, то можно заметить, что все работает так как и ожидалось.

Например:

```js
angular.module('app', ['ui.router']).config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $stateProvider
      .state('main', {
        url: '/',
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: 'templates/main.html'
      })
      .state('main.show', {
        url: 'show/:id/',
        templateUrl: 'templates/show.html',
        controller: 'Show',
      });
  })
  .controller('Main', function($scope, $state) {
    console.log('main');
    $scope.id = 123;
    $scope.open = function(id) {
      console.log('open', id);
      $state.go('main.show', {
        id: id
      });
    };
  })
  .controller('Show', function($scope, $stateParams) {
    console.log('show', $stateParams.id);
    $scope.param = $stateParams.id
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.2/angular-ui-router.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Main">
  <div ng-click="open(123)">
    Text
  </div>
  <ui-view></ui-view>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="templates/main.html">
    <div>Main</div>
    <ui-view></ui-vew>
  </script>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="templates/show.html">
    <div>Show</div>
    <div>{{param}}</div>
  </script>
</div>
```